# Share WiFi internet over same WiFi adapter

Tags: debian, networking, wifi, access-point

I am trying to share internet through my WiFi adapter which is in use for connection to that internet.
While I had Connectify license on Windows, I was able to do so:
Internet from: My Wifi adapter
Share through: My Wifi adapter
Simple as that!

 Since I migrated completely to Linux, and I'm not planning come back, I'm a bit disappointed that such powerful OS is that problematic for doing same thing which is possible on poor Windows.
Can somebody point me to right direction?

**My adapter is:** Alfa Network AWUS036NH

**Recognised on Linux:** Ralink Technology, Corp. RT2870/RT3070 Wireless Adapter

**OS:** Debian Jessie 8.1

Comment: Linux gives you more control over the process of sharing a connexion, but handles it with no simplifications as easy as one button in a configuration pannel. You have to configure your server to act as a `ROUTER`. Digging this way, you'll find some solution including for example `hostap` to allow clients to connect to your server as it would be a hotspot, and `netfilter` (which require several kernel module to be loaded, and some `iptable` commands)

Comment: you may have a look at my netfilter config file (placed in `/etc/network/if-up/`) http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/214178/howto-configure-linux-router-to-allow-clients-to-use-maximum-bandwidth

Comment: if you plan to connect to your server through an ethernet link, it's also possible to make a `bridge` instead of using netfilter, but a bridge is not possible between two wifi adapters

Comment: Nothing have worked. At end I have bought hardware solid TP-Link WA830RE v2 and installed DD-WRT on it. It's better solution anyway.

Comment: I've read tooday that 'network-manager' on ubuntu has a magic button to share internet connexion, I've never tried, maybe it's working well...

Comment: As far I remember it does, but not for sharing WiFi internet over same adapter, even if adapter actually supports that.